# Get GCM registration id using HTTP in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, google-cloud-messaging, react-native

I'm building a React Native app and want to include push notifications for Android. We currently have the infrastructure for GCM push from our last app. However this time I need to use the JS code to pass the registration id to our push servers. The old app was a native Java app and used:

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mActivityContext);
regid = getRegistrationId(mActivityContext);
```

I have the API key and sender Id but I need to get the `regid` using over HTTP not using the Java library used there. I have found `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/register` but I can't find any docs on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation for this can be done in 2 ways:

1. Do a volley implementation in android code and pass the result you get to the Javascript through the JS bridge.U can pass it in a form of promise to the javascript.Please refer to the following link:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/native-modules-android.html

2. Use fetch api.U can use body and headers in the fetch method.Please refer to the following link:

   http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/network.html#using-other-networking-libraries